# Prompting for user input to download tick data using R quantmod getSymbols function

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to prompt a user for console input of a ticker symbol (e.g. GOOG) and then use the getSymbols function in the quantmod package of R to download the tick data for the given ticker symbol and create a plot using quantmod's barChart function.

I have

```
s1 <- readline("enter a symbol: ")
getSymbols(cat('"',s1,'"',sep=""),src="yahoo")
barChart(s1)
```

I get the following error message "Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object"

Using just the console (without prompting for input) I get the following to work:

```
> getSymbols("GOOG",src="yahoo")
[1] "GOOG"
> barChart(GOOG)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

s1 is a character string, which isn't a time series object that is coercible to xts (as the error states)

Try:

```
s1 <- "AAPL"
getSymbols(s1)
barChart(get(s1))
```

Comment: You'll make Jeff a happy bunny if you tick the box to accept his answer as the right answer!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `cat` and `s1` is a character vector.  Another option to @Jeff's solution is to turn off automatic assignment:

```
s2 <- getSymbols(s1, auto.assign=FALSE)
barChart(s2)
```

The name of the chart will be "s2", but you can change it back to the ticker symbol with the `name` argument:

```
barChart(s2, name = s1)
```